# Exclude link to currently displayed page from random links pool

Tags: php

I am using this code sample to generate links to a couple of random, website subpages.
The issue I have with this method, is for example when I go to /test123 page, there's a big chance that this code will generate link to the same exact page.

What I want to do is to somehow exclude currently displayed page from random links pool.

How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
$links = array(array('url' => '/asd', 'name'=>'Go to Asd'),
               array('url' => '/test', 'name' => 'Go to Test'),
               array('url' => '/test123', 'name' => 'Go to Test123'));
$num = array_rand($links);
$item = $links[$num];

printf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $item['url'], $item['name'], $item['name']);
?>
```

Comment: Compare your current address with your new random address. That should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is to somehow exclude currently displayed page from random links pool.

I'd just remove this url from `$links` prior calling `array_rand()`.